# Need a regex for numbers followed by letters no spaces, dashes, slashes, etc

Tags: c#, regex

I'm just not that good at regex and I haven't been able to find an example of something close to what I need. Thanks in advance for your help. This is for a search entry box that will take the user directly to what they are looking for if they already know it's number or number+letter sequence

It has to start with a number and the number can be 1 to many digits, the letters following the numbers can be 0, 1, or 2 digits.

Examples of passing:
1
12
123456
123a
1234ab
123456789ab

Examples of failing:
a
ab
a1
ab12
1abc
123abc
1-a
1_a

you get the point. For the passing strings, I also need to separate the numbers from the letters.

Thanks again.

Language is c#. I need to test the incoming string and then split it into it's number and letter parts if it passes the regex.

Comment: @H2CO3 - It's C#, I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var regex=new Regex("^(?<numbers>[0-9]+)(?<letters>[a-z]{0,2})$",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match=regex.Match(testString);
```

The property `match.Success` tells you if it succeed and the values can be obtained

```
var numbers=match.groups["numbers"].Value;

var letters=match.groups["letters"].Value;
```

Comment: Selecting this as the right answer because it not only gave me the method to detect the match but also the method for exacting the values.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
[0-9]+[a-z]{0,2}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/([0-9]+)([a-z]{0,2})/
```

Depending upon what language you're using this regex in, the method for getting the full pattern match and subsequent subpattern matches may vary.

EDIT:

Revised second subpattern to match no letters, or a maximum of 2 letters.

Comment: " the letters following the numbers can be 0, 1, or 2 digits." so this is wrong, it would permit 123abcdef etc. It has to fail on more than 2 chars after the number.

Answer (score 1):

`/([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]{0,2})/` capitals...

Comment: well played, I forgot to include the fact that capital letters are also OK.

Comment: :P reputation grab for the easy code snippet questions...  speed v. accuracy.  In all fairness that should have just been a comment on your answer.

Comment: @djechlin the samples also suggested that capitals are not needed. Please do not accuse those who have responded earlier than you.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers given still match the 1-a in the failing list, so here's my addition:

```
\b([0-9]+)([a-z]{0,2})(?!-)\b
```

Tested with: 
    1 12 123456 123a 1234ab 123456789ab a ab a1 ab12 1abc 123abc 1-a 1_a

Matches:
    1 12 123456 123a 1234ab 123456789ab